# unable to retrieve picasa photos with php when requesting data feed

Tags: php, api, picasa

I tried to retrieve the latest 10 photos from my picasa account but it doesn't work.

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/firdawsfm?kind=photo&max-results=10&alt=json&access=public&thumbsize=".$tSize);
print_r($file);
```

the result :

```
     {"$t":"http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/firdawsfm"},"updated":{"$t":"2013-09-08T19:27:11.010Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
    "term":"http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#user"}],
    "title":{"$t":"108451527358440546192","type":"text"},
    "subtitle":{"$t":"","type":"text"},
    "icon":{"$t":"http://lh3.ggpht.com/-Srl88atqmQE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AhcCTIASEAM/s64-c/108451527358440546192.jpg"},
"link":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml",
"href":"http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/108451527358440546192?alt=json"},{"rel":"alternate",
"type":"text/html",
    "href":"https://picasaweb.google.com/108451527358440546192"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#slideshow",
"type":"application/x-shockwave-flash",
"href":"https://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/picasaweb.googleusercontent.com/slideshow.swf?host=picasaweb.google.com&RGB=0x000000&feed=http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/108451527358440546192?alt%3Drss"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml",
"href":"http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/108451527358440546192?alt=json&q=&start-index=1&max-results=10&kind=photo&thumbsize=180c&access=public"}],
"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Firdaws Haskell"},"uri":{"$t":"https://picasaweb.google.com/108451527358440546192"}}],
    "generator":{"$t":"Picasaweb",
    "version":"1.00",
    "uri":"http://picasaweb.google.com/"},
    "openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":0},
    "openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":1},"openSearch$itemsPerPage":{"$t":10},
    "gphoto$user":{"$t":"108451527358440546192"},"gphoto$nickname":{"$t":"Firdaws Haskell"},"gphoto$thumbnail":{"$t":"http://lh3.ggpht.com/-Srl88atqmQE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AhcCTIASEAM/s64-c/108451527358440546192.jpg"}}}
```

there is no data about photos. when I tried this exemple with another account it works. I verified the photos are public.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your url and all works fine, i can access gphoti$id and media$group values.
So far seems all ok ;) Try again!

Maybe you didn`t have public photos at that time there...

## Not relevant answer to that question

### (in case if server requests authorisation):

For all Picasa web albums api queries with alt=json, or alt=json-in-code and /userid/default/ you must provide access_token parameter.

Access token you can get using OAuth2 authorization work-flow as described here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2 (using google-api-php-client SDK for example)

And using in scopes this value "http://picasaweb.google.com/data/".

More how to do OAuth2 and get access token from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
after requesting user login: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth you can find on official website:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

In final you must have:

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/firdawsfm?kind=photo&max-results=10&alt=json&access=public&thumbsize=".$tSize."&access_token=".$access_token);
print_r($file);
```

Comment: @roman-m-kos Using oauth2 gives me two types of token: 1. `access_token` which expires after 3600sec and 2. `refresh_token`. Which one I need to append here?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam the answer to you question is in code. See for `$access_token` variable? `refresh _token` talks about it self. If you want to keep access token to be NOT expired, use `refresh_token` for that. For all request with authentication `access_token` is required.